# Is it possible to "turn off" the query to update Identity columns in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I've created a data migration tool using Entity Framework 5. When profiling the sql transactions I notice that EF does an insert and then immediately executes a select in order to retrieve an updated version of the record (including the primary key). However... I'm not really interested in the key as this is more of a fire and forget bulk insert operation. It seems to me that Inserting a few hundred thousand records would be quicker if I wasn't doing a few hundred thousand redundant Select statements that I don't need.

Anyone know a way to turn this behavior off?

For performance I have already turned off AutoDetectChangesEnabled and ValidateOnSaveEnabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn it off but doing so will stop related entities from having their FK values being set.

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption)